# How can I filer out rows with NULL in PostgresQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, null

I am joining a lot of tables and I have a result set that looks like:

```
  ID1 ID2 ID3
  -----------
  1   1   1
  1   1   NULL
  1   2   1
  1   2   2
  1   2   NULL
  1   3   NULL
```

I would like to ignore rows with ID3=NULL only if another row exists where ID1 and ID2 are the same, so the result set should look like:

```
  ID1 ID2 ID3
  -----------
  1   1   1
  1   2   1
  1   2   2
  1   3  NULL
```

I was hoping to use something clever that didn't require a nested query, but I haven't figure out any approach yet.  DISTINCT, MAX, etc. for filtering the ID3 value in the result set hasn't panned out. There are about a dozen tables that I'm joining to get the results set, so providing that source table definition is a little difficult.  Does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(t.id3) over (partition by id1, id2) as maxid3
      from t
     ) t
where maxid3 is null or id3 is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OR along with an EXISTS clause:

```
SELECT m.ID1,
    m.ID2,
    m.ID3
FROM MyTable m
WHERE m.ID3 IS NOT NULL
    OR (m.ID3 IS NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable s WHERE s.ID1 = m.ID1 AND s.ID2 = m.ID2 AND s.ID3 IS NOT NULL)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Other variation of window function with count is more explicit about conditions of your select:

```
SELECT ID1, ID2, ID3 
FROM (
 SELECT 
  t.*,
  COUNT(ID3) OVER(PARTITION BY (ID1, ID2)) AS n
 FROM myTable t
) ot 
WHERE NOT (n > 0 AND ID3 IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
with t(i1,i2,i3) as (values(1,1,1),(1,1,null),(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,2,null),(1,3,null))
select
  i1,i2,
  unnest(coalesce(array_agg(i3) filter (where i3 is not null),array[null]::int[]))
from t
group by i1,i2;
```